# Display looks fine on Android Studio designer but wrong in emulator or physical device

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

The display on the designer is what it should look like, but it messes up when it's on an emulator or physical device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chat Fragment"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

[Display on android studio designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwtHx.png)

[Display on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L9qx.png)

Comment: Where is the closing tag of RelativeLayout?

Comment: Sorry, I left it out when I was copying the code.